# How to ensure only patternProperties that match a particular pattern

Tags: python

I'm using python module validictory to validate dicts / yaml configs.

Given the following schema I want to match any count of keys that match "^[0-9x]{3}$" and validate the value with another pattern.

```
SCHEMA = {
    "type": "object",
    "patternProperties": {
        "^[0-9x]{3}$": {
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "^somepattern$"
        }
    }
}
```

This works so far but what I want now is:

```
SCHEMA = {
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": False,
    "patternProperties": {
        "^[0-9x]{3}$": {
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "^somePattern$"
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work as I would expect, it seems if additionalProperties is present patternProperties is not evaluated resulting in an error that no keys are allowed that aren't specified in properties.

So how could I ensure that every key in the config follows that exact pattern ("^[0-9x]{3}$")?

Example configs:

```
{
    '5xx': 'someValidValue',
    'x9x': 'someValidValue'
}
```

-> should test True

```
{
    '5xx': 'someValidValue',
    'foobar': 'someValidValue', #this one should fail
    'baz': 'someValidValue',    #this one, too
    'x9x1': 'someValidValue',   #this one, too
    'x9x': 'someValidValue'
}
```

-> should test False

I tried to "define own type" like documentation says, by giving a pattern within the type block:

```
...
"type": { "pattern": "^[0-9x]{3}$" }
...
```

But then it actually tests the values against that pattern, so either I did it wrong or got the documentation wrong (or both).

Note: I have (and want) to use validictory since it is a set module for some 3rd party libs I'm using.

EDIT: Ok, after smarx's answer I wondered what went wrong here an after a few times I thought I screwed something up I finally couldn't really find something wrong with my scheme. But I think I found the problem:

Here's a more production like example, like the schema generator I'm building gives me (cut down to the necessary):

```
import validictory

data = {
    'tests': {
        'default': {
            'timeout_status': 'amber',
            'sensor': 'http',
            'modules': {
                'statuscode': {'200': 'red'}
            }
        },
        'tgoogle': {
            'sensor': 'http',
            'modules': {
                'statuscode': {
                    '200': 'green',
                    'foo': 'bar',
                },
            },
            'timeout_status': 'amber'
        }
    }, 
    # ... more besides key tests
}

SCHEMA = {
    'type': 'object',
    'properties': {
        'tests': {
            'additionalProperties': {
                'type': 'object',
                'properties': {
                    'timeout_status': {
                        'enum': ['amber', 'yellow', 'green', 'red'],
                        'type': 'string'
                    }, 
                    'sensor': {
                        'pattern': '^\S+$',
                        'type': 'string'
                    }, 
                    'modules': {
                        'additionalProperties': False,
                        'type': 'object',
                        'properties': {
                            'statuscode': {
                                'additionalProperties': False,
                                'required': False,
                                'type': 'object',
                                'patternProperties': {
                                    '^[0-9x]{3}': {
                                        'enum': ['amber', 'yellow', 'green', 'red'],
                                        'type': 'string',
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            # ... more available test modules
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            'type': 'object'
        },
        # ... more besides key tests
    }
}

validictory.validate(data, SCHEMA) #<- this fails as expected at foo
#validictory.validate(data, SCHEMA, fail_fast=False) #<- this throws the exception from below
```

-> This works as expected

I think two major things went wrong here:

1. I had a way too old validictory lib installed, I think this was the reason for the original missbehavior -> never use debian packages even on a debian8 they are from stone age -.- better use pip

After upgrading to 1.0.2 I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 71, in <module>
    validictory.validate(should_work, SCHEMA, fail_fast=False) # no exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/validictory/__init__.py", line 43, in validate
    return v.validate(data, schema)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/validictory/validator.py", line 590, in validate
    self.__validate("data", {"data": data}, schema, '<obj>')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/validictory/validator.py", line 632, in __validate
    validator(data, fieldname, schema, path, newschema.get(schemaprop))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/validictory/validator.py", line 285, in validate_properties
    path + '.' + property)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/validictory/validator.py", line 632, in __validate
    validator(data, fieldname, schema, path, newschema.get(schemaprop))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/validictory/validator.py", line 398, in validate_additionalProperties
    self.__validate(eachProperty, value, additionalProperties, path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/validictory/validator.py", line 632, in __validate
    validator(data, fieldname, schema, path, newschema.get(schemaprop))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/validictory/validator.py", line 285, in validate_properties
    path + '.' + property)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/validictory/validator.py", line 632, in __validate
    validator(data, fieldname, schema, path, newschema.get(schemaprop))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/validictory/validator.py", line 285, in validate_properties
    path + '.' + property)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/validictory/validator.py", line 632, in __validate
    validator(data, fieldname, schema, path, newschema.get(schemaprop))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/validictory/validator.py", line 398, in validate_additionalProperties
    self.__validate(eachProperty, value, additionalProperties, path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/validictory/validator.py", line 599, in __validate
    (fieldname, type(schema).__name__))
validictory.validator.SchemaError: Type for field 'foo' must be 'dict', got: 'bool'
```

Actually I called validictory like that:

```
validictory.validate(data, SCHEMA, fail_fast=False)
```

After removing the fail_fast=False everything is working like expected, so:

2. Maybe there is a bug in fail_fast=False ? (I actually successfully tested it before using it but with much simpler schemas)

-> If someone sees anything that's wrong with my schema, potentially breaking validictory's code, I would be happy to know.

-> If not, I hope I can save someone some hours with that hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your issue. This code works as expected for me (Python 3.5.1, validictory 1.0.2), unless I'm misunderstanding your question?

```
import validictory

should_work = {
    '5xx': 'someValidValue',
    'x9x': 'someValidValue'
}

should_not_work = {
    '5xx': 'someValidValue',
    'foobar': 'someValidValue', #this one should fail
    'baz': 'someValidValue',    #this one, too
    'x9x1': 'someValidValue',   #this one, too
    'x9x': 'someValidValue'
}

SCHEMA = {
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": False,
    "patternProperties": {
        "^[0-9x]{3}$": {
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "^someValidValue$"
        },
    },
}

validictory.validate(should_work, SCHEMA) # no exception

validictory.validate(should_not_work, SCHEMA)
# validictory.validator.FieldValidationError ... contains additional property 'baz' not defined by 'properties' or 'patternProperties' and additionalProperties  is False
```

Comment: Ok, I should have stated, I'm using python 2.7.9.

Even weirder: after upgrading to validictory 1.0.2 "additionalProperties": False gets me an exception that it needs to be type dict not bool

Comment: Actually the example is working even with 2.7.9 but its just a simplified example for the question, in reality this structure is nested deeper in a schema, I will post an update.